# App with derby database - client access needs changing to embedded?

Tags: java, derby

I'm still rather new to java and I think I've started a project with a problem.

I created a job for a friend in which there are employees, shifts, sites and these needed to be loaded at the beginning.

I went looking for solutions and decided to use a Derby database. I've now programmed the Application and it works fine with the database. It loads all parameters and creates objects for handling,

Now I need to deploy my project to my friends computer so he can use it and I think I have the database set up wrong. I think I needed it to be embedded? so it goes with the application.

So my questions are what are my choices,

I read I can change the database to an 'embedded' one by making the database a class? I have no idea how to do this and maybe because I'm new to java, I'm finding all the write ups on this subject difficult to understand.

Alternatively I thought maybe I can install Derby separately and connect to that?

Or maybe I can drop the Derby idea and switch entirely to another database entirely,

I'm a bit confused over my choices here, basically I've built an application around an installation of Derby DB using this line to connect to it.
`jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/SG_database`

If someone can give me some 'Plain English' options here I would very much appreciate it.

Comment: This question seems to be [superseded by the OP's next question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39053060/change-derbyclient-to-embedded) - see an earlier edit of that post.

Answer (score 0):

To reconfigure your application to use Derby as an embedded database, all you have to do is change that JDBC Connection URL to `jdbc:derby:SG_database`, and change your `CLASSPATH` so that your program references `derby.jar` rather than `derbyclient.jar`. You should possibly add `;create=true` to the end of that URL so that, the first time your friend runs your application, the database is created on their machine.

But yes, you have other choices, and without knowing a fair amount about your application it's hard to give you very detailed guidance.

When your friend is using the application, do you want you and your friend to be sharing the same set of data? Or is your application designed so that your data and your friend's data have nothing in common?

If you want to be sharing the data, then yes it will be important to have a single instance of the database, and both of you have to share it, in which case a client-server configuration can work quite well.

If you want to be two completely separate applications, with nothing shared, and each of you has your own copy of the data, then an embedded configuration can work quite well.

Perhaps you could simply try the embedded configuration, see how it behaves with your application, and then return here if you have a more specific question to ask?

Comment: Yes it is completely separate. The app just needs to store the info in the database when not running. So embedded is the route to go,

...and I know this is going to be a question I'll look back at and cringe but.....Where do I locate the CLASSPATH ?

Comment: You set `CLASSPATH` with the `-cp` flag to `java`, or with the `CLASSPATH` environment variable. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html

Comment: I'm still struggling here, I cannot find an environment variable for either derby driver - Im really new to this, My current CLASSPATH variable is as follows :-

Comment: C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\iis express\PHP\v5.3;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\80\Tools\Binn\;. . . . . . . . . . . . . .C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Universal Extractor;C:\Program Files (x86)\Universal Extractor\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\

Comment: basically I need to move this to another PC and I'm clueless, I thought it was going to be easy?

Comment: When you copy your application's jar file to another PC, you can **also** copy the derby.jar file to another PC. The derby.jar file is designed to be copied from machine to machine. That is the concept of having the Derby code **embedded** in your application: the derby.jar library is simply a library of code that you include in your application. So after you copy both your program and the derby.jar to the new PC, set the CLASSPATH on the new PC to point to those two jar files (your app and derby.jar), with a semicolon between them.

Comment: BTW, the string you pasted above looks much more like a PATH setting than a CLASSPATH setting. They are two different things. You probably want to re-read those tutorial links I posted in my Aug-2 comment.

Comment: OK I added '; %DERBY_HOME%\bin' to the end of my system Path variable in the Control Panel, re-booted and changed the connection url as shown above but Ive got this error? No suitable driver found for jdbc:derby:SG_database;create=true

Comment: thank you very much Bryan, I shall digest in the morning. I panic sometimes thinking I souldn't have taken this on. Its my first app of any size and Im pulling my hair out with it. Still, I'm committed now, there is omly this and I need to figure out REST so i can connect it to an SMS service and its sort of done!

Comment: Ok I think Im getting there, I changed the CLASSPATH variable to add the derby.jar file, I changed the connection string and Im getting an error saying the tables do not exist. Do I now have to recreate the tables etc and if so how, there was a connection to the last database I used.

Comment: Failed to start database 'SG_database' with class loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@2626b418, see the next exception for details. - any ideas why Im getting this, I was just thinking I had cracked this and . . .  . . .

Comment: HEEEELLLLPPP!!!!!!!!! - DERBY SQL error: ERRORCODE: 40000, SQLSTATE: XJ040, SQLERRMC: Failed to start database 'SG_database' with class loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@5e2de80c, see the next exception for details.::SQLSTATE: XSDB6

Comment: I cannot run the project with the server set as embedded, it states the errors above. I can switch back to the localhost connection and all is well. I'm hoping someone will help me with this.....

Comment: When it says "see the next exception for details", follow these steps to uncover the root cause of the problem: http://wiki.apache.org/db-derby/UnwindExceptionChain